# ASP.NET child window opens up on a new window on every post back

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I have an asp.net page with a grid. On RowDateBound event

```
mybutton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:window.showModalDialog('some.aspx?ID="
                                                                    + mybutton.CommandArgument + 
                                                                    "','window.self','dialogWidth:800px; dialogHeight:800px;center:yes; status:yes; scroll:no; help:no');");
```

on some.aspx page I have dropdowns and asp.net button that does a postback.On postback the some.aspx page opens again in a new window (Browser).

How to prevent this?

I appreciate your support.

Comment: Does the button even have a server-side component?  It sounds like all it's doing is opening a pop-up on the client side.  If that's the case, make it a regular button instead of an ASP.NET server control and it'll never even try to post back in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had this problem before with ASP.NET and a ModalDialog. What you need to do is set the `<base target="_self">` tag in the head of the page. It sounds too simple to be correct but it's what fixed it for me.

This frustrated me quite a bit.

If you need any help with this, just ask.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Page</title>
  <base target="_self">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Your content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! showModalDialog has this issue. Your suggestion made it work.

Comment: @Krik I am facing similar issue where all of my links open in a new window. I tried your suggestion but still no luck. Here is the link to the my posting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254677/why-all-my-links-opening-in-a-new-window

Comment: Thanks you so much i have struggled very much for this. again thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can place a `return false;` behind the link / button to stop the post back from happening.

Comment: The Grid is on the parent page. The child window (some.aspx) should have postback (dropdown and buttons) happening correctly. return false; doesn't help. I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: I guess i dont understand your problem, can you give more details in your post.

Comment: Are the controls on `some.aspx` updating the parent? Is the parent page being refreshed by the controls in `some.aspx`?