# Why all my links opening in a new Window?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Recently i upgraded a web project from Framework 2.0 to 4.0

On my main page there are several links. Upon clicking on them it opens within the same window.

There is one link to a page which contains a Crystal Report Viewer. Once i visit that page and return back to the  main page, after that clicking on any link opens it in a new window !!

I double checked my urls, there is nothing wrong with them.

What is causing this behaviour ? and how do i prevent this ?

**NOTE** : The pages load inside a frame

thanks

**EDIT** : This happens in IE only

**EDIT 2** : I also tried suggestion by Krik in this post [ASP.NET child window opens up on a new window on every post back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391080/asp-net-child-window-opens-up-on-a-new-window-on-every-post-back) and added `<base target="_self">` but it is not working.

**EDIT 3** : This how my links are

```
<a class="MenuLinks" target="display" href="../REP/LdgrRep.aspx?pageId=34&mId=1&subModuelId=3">Party Ledger</a>
```

where `display` being the name of my frame.

Comment: care to explain the vote down ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention the name of your frame is *display*. Also make sure to set the *id* to *display* too.

This may explain your issue. Some browsers work with both *name* and *id* for this and some don't.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML code when you make a link tag if you have target="_blank" that causes it to open the link in a new window.

Check of all your

Comment: No Kevin. this is how my links are http://..../MyApp/PL/REP/InstlDue.aspx?pageId=35&mId=1&subModuelId=3

Comment: In your HTML code what does the tag look like? It should be <a href="link here"> but if it looks like <a href="link here" target="_blank"> then it would open in a new window.

Comment: i use target="myframe". plz see my edit. Anyway it works for the 1st time. But from second time onwards things become different

Comment: Can you link me to the website this is occuring on?

Comment: Also your code there show the target="display" just take the target out completely. It should make them open in the same window. If not it could be an issue in your class "MenuLinks".

Comment: i am sorry but class menulinks define font and text decoration only. I checked in firebug too. the problem only occurs if i visit a page containing crystal report and come back. that too in IE only. Firefox renders fine.

Comment: after making the target="_self" in each link now it renders fine. But when i use frame name it does not.

Comment: yes but i have to specify framename in some links as target. That is where i am stuck. probably crystal report has some issue with a frame named "display". I upvoted your answer anyway because of your comment to remove target. it helped partially though. Thanks

Comment: I will do some research in to this and see if I can figure anything out. Hopefully we can fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your time.